What happened to "Source Code Viewer Pro" in Android Playstore
The "Source Code Viewer PRO" once stood out as my premier source code viewer for Android. However, it has ceased functioning as of late. Upon attempting to locate it on the Google Playstore, it appears to have been removed. Can anyone shed light on the circumstances surrounding the disappearance of this Android application?
